# In a Combine Publisher chain, how to keep inner objects alive until cancel or complete?

Tags: swift, combine

I've created a Combine publisher chain that looks something like this:

```
let pub = getSomeAsyncData()
           .mapError { ... }
           .map { ... }
           ...
           .flatMap { data in 
               let wsi = WebSocketInteraction(data, ...)
               return wsi.subject
           }
           .share().eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

It's a flow of different possible network requests and data transformations. The calling code wants to subscribe to `pub` to find out when the whole asynchronous process has succeeded or failed.

I'm confused about the design of the `flatMap` step with the `WebSocketInteraction`. That's a helper class that I wrote. I don't think its internal details are important, but its purpose is to provide its `subject` property (a `PassthroughSubject`) as the next Publisher in the chain. Internally the `WebSocketInteraction` uses `URLSessionWebSocketTask`, talks to a server, and publishes to the `subject`. I like `flatMap`, but how do you keep this piece alive for the lifetime of the Publisher chain?

If I store it in the outer object (no problem), then I need to clean it up. I could do *that* when the `subject` completes, but if the caller *cancels* the entire publisher chain then I won't receive a completion event. Do I need to use `Publisher.handleEvents` and listen for cancellation as well? This seems a bit ugly. But maybe there is no other way...

```
.flatMap { data in 
    let wsi = WebSocketInteraction(data, ...)
    self.currentWsi = wsi  // store in containing object to keep it alive.
    wsi.subject.sink(receiveCompletion: { self.currentWsi = nil })
    wsi.subject.handleEvents(receiveCancel: {
        wsi.closeWebSocket()
        self.currentWsi = nil
    })
```

Anyone have any good "design patterns" here?

One design I've considered is making my own `Publisher`. For example, instead of having `WebSocketInteraction` vend a `PassthroughSubject`, it could conform to `Publisher`. I may end up going this way, but making a custom Combine `Publisher` is more work, and the documentation steers people toward using a subject instead. To make a custom Publisher you have to implement some of things that the `PassthroughSubject` does for you, like respond to demand and cancellation, and keep state to ensure you complete at most once and don't send events after that.

[Edit: to clarify that `WebSocketInteraction` is my own class.]

Comment: No need to store anything. Basically `flatMap` produces a publisher, _retains it,_ and lets it keep publishing, until another piece of data comes from upstream, at which point it keeps retaining it and letting it publish but also produces and retains another one and lets it publish too, merging the outputs into a single stream — and it keeps doing that, piling up publishers, unless you have set `maxPublishers` to do otherwise. Downstream cancellation cancels all the retained publishers. If that’s what you want, fine. If not, this could be the wrong operator.

Comment: Yes, `flatMap` retains the *publisher*. But when you have a helper object like I do, (`WebSocketInteraction`), which is not the publisher itself but is sending things to the publisher (the `subject`, which is a  `PassthroughSubject`), then the helper has no strong reference to it.

Comment: Well I’m afraid I don’t know anything about WebSocketInteraction, I’ve never heard of it.

Comment: @RobN, what's your goal here? Do you need `WebSocketInteraction` to keep publishing through the subject? For how long? Until you unsubscribe from the chain publisher?

Comment: The goal is to implement a multi-step asynchronous network interaction in a way that can be viewed, by the calling code, as simply a `Publisher` that either delivers the final answer or an error. So the `WebSocketInteraction` is somewhat like a `Future`. It's going to go back and forth with a server and then publish a result or an error. One reason I didn't use `Future` itself is that I want to be able to *cancel* the whole process as well. The UI will show an activity Spinner and a cancel button for the user.

Comment: While this is process is going to result in just one value, like a `Future`, I can imagine other similar cases where I'd want the inner publisher to continue publishing until the whole chain is cancelled/unsubscribed.

Comment: Hmm.. You can combine `Future` with `handleEvents` operator to cancel. Return that in your API of `WebSocketInteraction` @RobN

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what problems you are facing with keeping an inner object alive. The object should be alive so long as something has a strong reference to it.

It's either an external object that will start some async process, or an internal closure that keeps a strong reference to `self` via `self.subject.send(...)`.

```
class WebSocketInteraction {
   private let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Error>()

   private var isCancelled: Bool = false

   init() {
      // start some async work
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
         if !isCancelled { self.subject.send("Done") } // <-- ref
      } 
   }

   // return a publisher that can cancel the operation when
   var pub: AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
      subject
         .handleEvents(receiveCancel: {
             print("cancel handler")
             self.isCancelled = true  // <-- ref
         })
         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
}
```

You should be able to use it as you wanted with `flatMap`, since the `pub` property returned publisher, and the inner closure hold a reference to `self`

```
let pub = getSomeAsyncData()
           ...
           .flatMap { data in 
               let wsi = WebSocketInteraction(data, ...)
               return wsi.pub
           }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to tinker with this a little. The work item is creating a cycle that will prevent the object from being deallocated, no? I need to think about the second closure.

Comment: @RobN, yes, that's true. I only used it for illustrative purposes of a cancellable task, so I'll remove it (or maybe just add weak self)